# Installing Windows 10 multiple times?

Tags: windows-10

I want to reinstall Windows using Windows 10 Pro CD - legal version.
I already did it for 3 times.

Is there a limit that prevents e.g. five installs of one product?

Comment: You aren't running Sysprep, are you?  If not, then the simple answer is "no," that shouldn't be a problem.  The official [Windows 10 Activation guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12440/windows-10-activation) will help explain things in greater detail.

Comment: On Windows 10, you're supposed to use the tools that Windows give you, and reset the installation from the Reset menu. If that is still not enough for you, you have not a limit of reinstalls (although I can't find a Microsoft page to back this affirmation) as long as it is in the same computer

Comment: *Is there any limit that prevents installing multiple times on one computer (like in some antivirus programs)?* - Nope;  Your machine has a digital entitlement;

Comment: I don't think you need online activation if your hardware came with windows 10. The license is embedded in the hardware and doesn't care. I've reinstalled windows 10 100 times on my laptop without internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're reinstalling on the same computer, than this will not cause an issue-- Windows should reactivate without any kind of intervention eeded.

If you are switching the hardware you are using (or the computer as a whole), then there are stipulations such as you can't run more than one copy of the software at a time, so the old drive with that copy of Windows would need reformatted.  You may have to reactive using the phone method instead of online.

Now, if you're talking about using the same disk to install on multiple computers with different keys, there is no problem with that.